# What does the python tuple multiplied by some constant mean?

Tags: python, tuples

I read some python codes like follows:

```
color = (1.0,)*4
```

I couldn't figure out what does it mean? (1.0,) means some tuple, but what does it mean by multiplying 4 here?

Comment: Have you checked what happens if you put it into a python shell?

Comment: Note that the simplest way to answer questions like this is to open the python.exe interactive shell and try it yourself!

Comment: Hi, guys thanks for your tips. Running them in the shell might give me  the result quickly, but I still need to get to know what kind of concept I'm facing. I've googled "python tuple multiplied by constant", seems I didn't get some useful information any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a new tuple with 4 times the same referenced value.

```
>>> (1.0,) * 4
(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
```

See the [Sequence types reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)

> `s * n, n * s`
>     `n` shallow copies of `s` concatenated

Note that it's the *exact same value* that is reused; you see this when you use a mutable value:

```
>>> lst = []
>>> tup = (lst,) * 4
>>> tup[0] is lst
True
>>> all(i is lst for i in tup)
True
```

Comment: Hi, Martijin, thank for the quick answer, would you please give me some reference link somewhere, sorry I can't find any.

Comment: Brava. This is exactly what I want.